# ActiveMQ broker - limit connections per client

Tags: activemq-classic, amqp

I am trying to find an option in ActiveMQ (5.13) that would allow me to configure the broker with a maximum number of amqp connections from one client. The target is to prevent one malicious or malfunctioning client to consume all the connections available on the broker preventing other clients to connect.

I am aware of the possibility to set maximumConnections on the transportConnector, but, as long as I understand correctly, this is a global limit on all the connections so it would not help in this case.

Is my understanding of the maximumConnections correct?
Is there a way to configure maxConnections per client on the broker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such property for a per client limit in ActiveMQ.  You'd first need to narrow down what you define as a single client as that can be defined differently by different people.  IP Address might not work as there can be several different applications coming from a single address depending on network topology or application co-location within a single box etc.